# Ember js : deleteRecord TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Here is the problem, I have feed definition which has sections with many to many relation ship. That mean, 1 feed definition can have multiple section and 1 section can have multiple feed definition.

When I display fee, I have to display the list of sections with whom it is associated. Please check sections in the model.

If some one wants to delete that association, I have a separate model called section feed which is a separate table. So, on delete action, I fetch the section feed entry and try to delete but I am getting below error.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Error place

```
this.store.find("sectionfeed", {
                       sectionDefintionID : section.id
                       feedDefinitionID : feed.id
                       }).then(function (sectionfeed) {
                          sectionfeed.deleteRecord(); //is not working. Here I get the error
                          sectionfeed.save();
                       });
```

I am able to fetch the section feed but on section.deleteRecord I get the error. Please see below the complete information.

Setup

```
 DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.9
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1
ember.js:14463 DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

template

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        {{go-back}}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="pull-left lead"> {{displayTitle}} </div>
        {{link-to 'Edit' 'feeddefinition.edit' this class="edit-button btn btn-primary btn-sm"}}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td><strong> Id </strong></td>
                <td> {{id}} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong> Title </strong></td>
                <td> {{displayTitle}} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong> Url </strong></td>
                <td><a {{bind-attr href=url}} target="_blank"> {{url}} </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong> Link </strong></td>
                <td><a {{bind-attr href=link}} target="_blank"> {{link}} </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong> Disabled </strong></td>
                <td> {{disabled}} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong> Created </strong></td>
                <td>{{createdAt}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong> Last Modified </strong></td>
                <td> {{modifiedAt}} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover channels">
                    <thead>
                    <th> Name</th>
                    <th> Created</th>
                    <th> Modified</th>
                    <th> Updated</th>
                    <th> Liverpooled</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {{#each section in model.sections}}
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{#link-to 'section' section}}{{section.name}}{{/link-to}} </td>
                            <td> {{fromNow section.createdAt}} </td>
                            <td> {{fromNow section.modifiedAt}} </td>
                            <td> {{fromNow section.updatedAt}} </td>
                            <td> {{fromNow section.liverpooledAt}} </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" {{action 'remove' model section}}>Remove</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {{ else }}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">
                        No Section found.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {{/each}}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model of feed definition which contains sections

```
/*global Ember*/
Backoffice.Feeddefinition = DS.Model.extend({
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    modifiedAt: DS.attr('date'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    link: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    disabled: DS.attr('boolean'),
    automaticallyAdded: DS.attr('boolean'),
    userAdded: DS.attr('boolean'),
    sections: DS.hasMany('sections', {async: true}),
    displayTitle: function () {
        return this.get('title') === '' ? 'No Title' : this.get('title');
    }.property('title')
});

// probably should be mixed-in...
Backoffice.Feeddefinition.reopen({
    attributes: function () {
        var model = this;
        return Ember.keys(this.get('data')).map(function (key) {
            return Em.Object.create({ model: model, key: key, valueBinding: 'model.' + key });
        });
    }.property()
});
```

Model of section feed - which is many to many relation between feed and section

/*global Ember*/

```
Backoffice.Sectionfeed = DS.Model.extend({
    sectionDefinitionID: DS.attr('string'),
    feedDefinitionID: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Router of feed

```
Backoffice.FeeddefinitionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.get('store').find('feeddefinition', params.feeddefinition_id);
    },
    actions: {
            remove: function (feed, section) {
                var model = this.model;
                this.store.find("sectionfeed", {
                       sectionDefintionID : section.id
                       feedDefinitionID : feed.id
                       }).then(function (sectionfeed) {
                          sectionfeed.deleteRecord(); //is not working. Here I get the error
                          sectionfeed.save();
                       });
            }
    }
});
```

Error

```
ember.js:14463 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/combined-scripts.js:1492:33
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45818:16)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45830:17)
    at publish (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45801:11)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:29069:9
    at DeferredActionQueues.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:634:18)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:684:15)
    at Object.Backburner.end (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:147:27)
    at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:202:20)
    at apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js:18382:27)
ember.js:3722 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

REST API is written in java. Below is the endpoint

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/sectionfeeds", method = {RequestMethod.DELETE})
    public void remove(@RequestBody String body) throws Exception {
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(body);
        SectionFeed sectionFeed = objectMapper.reader(SectionFeed.class).readValue(jsonNode.get("sectionfeed"));
        sectionFeedManager.remove(sectionFeed.getSectionDefinitionID(), sectionFeed.getFeedDefinitionID());
    }
```

Finder method

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/sectionfeeds", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> get(@RequestParam(value = "sectionDefinitionID", required = true) String sectionDefinitionId,
                @RequestParam(value = "feedDefinitionID", required = true) String feedDefinitionId) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(sectionDefinitionId);
    System.out.println(feedDefinitionId);
    SectionFeed sectionFeed = sectionFeedManager.find(UUID.fromString(sectionDefinitionId),
                            UUID.fromString(feedDefinitionId));
    return createReturnMap("sectionfeed",sectionFeed, null);
}
```

From the comment below, I made changes

```
actions: {
        remove: function (feed, section) {
            var model = this.model;
            var sectionfeed = this.store.find("sectionfeed", {
                   sectionDefinitionID:section.id,
                   feedDefinitionID : feed.id
                   });
            var sfeed = sectionfeed.get("sectionfeed");
            sfeed.deleteRecord();
            sfeed.save();
        }
}
```

After that I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteRecord' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because your query to the store is returning an array. [as per the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/#toc_querying-for-records)

> If you provide a plain object as the second argument to find, Ember
>   Data will make a GET request with the object serialized as query
>   params. This method returns DS.PromiseArray in the same way as find
>   with no second argument.
>
> For example, we could search for all person models who have the name
>   of Peter:

```
var peters = this.store.find('person', { name: "Peter" }); // => GET to /persons?name='Peter
```

If you check if it is returning an array, and not an object, and then call the `deleteRecord()` on the first object in that array

Comment: Editted the question with find. it returns the map with key as 'section feed' and one object as a value

Comment: if you log sfeed - whats printed to console?